# SQL - table having different values for different points in time - best practise?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite, crud

i'm currently designing a database for logging some values for a specific time horizon. For illustration let's just say that i have a table with the following columns as the primary key:

**Name | someInteger | anotherInteger**

I want to log values different values for the same primary key for example for 30 seconds. So for example there may be multiple records with the same "Name","SomeInteger", "AnotherInteger" where only the "Timestamp" is guaranteed to differ from the other records.

**"ExampleName" | 1  | 3 | Timestamp1** | Value1
**"ExampleName" | 1  | 3 | Timestamp2** | Value2
**"ExampleName" | 1  | 3 | Timestamp3** | Value3
...

That means that i would include the Timestamp column as part of the primary key. I'm currently wondering whats the best database design (or best practise) to do so? Should i just include a Timestamp column as part of the primary key or is there a better solution?

Thank you very much in advance.
Ingo

Answer (score 0):

> there may be multiple records for the same primary key like:

You seem quite confused.  A primary key is -- by definition -- unique.  Your table is fine, but the primary key (as described) is a compound primary key.

You seem to need two tables.  One would be your entity:

```
create table entity (
    EntityId int auto_increment primary key,
    Name varchar(255) not null,
    someInteger int not null,
    anotherInteger int not null,
    unique (name, someInteger, anotherInteger)
);

create table entityValues (
    entityValueId int auto_increment primary key,
    EntityId int,
    timestamp datetime,
    value ?,  -- I don't know what the type is
    foreign key (EntityId) references entities(EntityId)
);
```

This uses MySQL syntax.  You can do the same thing in SQLite.

Comment: Oh yes you're right. I somehow forgot to mention that i wanted to include the timestamp as part of the primary key, which then makes it unique again. I'll edit the question.